# A family of subspaces of $\mathbb R^4$ which does not intersect non-trivially a rational subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

*This question is somehow linked to [this previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2969101/is-this-particular-subspace-of-mathbb-r4-intersecting-non-trivially-a-ration) I asked earlier.*

---

Let's consider the following family $F$ of subspaces of dimension $2$ of $\mathbb R^4$. A subspace $A$ is in $F$ if it admits a basis of the form $(Y_1,Y_2)$ where

$$\begin{cases} Y_1=(0,1,\xi,\xi^2), \\ Y_2=(1,0,\xi^2,\xi).\end{cases},$$

with $\xi\notin\mathbb Q$.

I am interested in the following problem:

> For every $A\in F$, does there exist a rational subspace $B$ of $\mathbb R^4$ of dimension $2$, such that $\dim(A\cap B)\geqslant 1$?

**Some context.**

- By *rational subspace*, I mean a subspace of $\mathbb R^4$ which admits a rational basis, in other words a basis $(a,b)$ with $a,b\in\mathbb Q^4$.
- For instance, the vector $v=(0,\xi,3\xi,\xi-\xi^2)$ is in a rational subspace of dimension $2$ since:

$$v=\xi\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 3 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}+\xi^2\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ -1\end{pmatrix}.$$

- I conjecture the answer to be *no*, but I can't prove it so far.
- We can reformulate the problem the following way: does there exist a vector $v\in A\setminus\{0\}$ such that

$$\exists \xi_1,\xi_2\in\mathbb R,\quad \exists r_1,r_2\in\mathbb Q,\quad v=r_1\xi_1+r_2\xi_2\quad ?$$

- We can write the problem in coordinates, which leads us to find $\alpha,\beta,\xi_1,\xi_2\in\mathbb R$ and $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2,c_1,c_2,d_1,d_2\in\mathbb Q$, such that

$$\alpha Y_1+\beta Y_2=a \xi_1+b\xi_2,$$

which gives

$$\begin{cases} \beta=a_1\xi_1+b_1\xi_2 \\ \alpha=a_2\xi_1+b_2\xi_2 \\ \alpha\xi^2+\beta\xi=a_3\xi_1+b_3\xi_2 \\ \alpha\xi+\beta\xi^2 = a_4\xi_2+b_4\xi_2,\end{cases}$$

but it does not seem to help at all.

---

Since I am quite stuck with this problem, any help, hints, or new ways to look at the problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: In your reformulation you write $\exists r_1,r_2\in\Bbb{Q}$?, but do you mean $\exists r_1,r_2\in\Bbb{Q}^4$ in stead? I also believe the answer is indeed *no*, I will try to write up an answer shortly.

Comment: @Servaes No, I meant $r_1,r_2\in\mathbb Q$. Thank you for the answer, I'll read it!

Comment: But then the statement makes no sense; if $\xi_1,\xi_2\in\Bbb{R}$ and $r_1,r_2\in\Bbb{Q}$ then $v=r_1\xi_1+r_2\xi_2\notin A$.

Comment: I guess in the system should be $a_3\xi_1$ instead of $a_2\xi_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only does such a rational subspace $B$ exist for all $A\in F$, but in fact there is a single rational subspace $B$ that intersects *all* $A\in F$ nontrivially: Note that for any $\xi\in\Bbb{R}$ we have
$$(0,1,\xi,\xi^2)+(1,0,\xi^2,\xi)=(1,1,\xi+\xi^2,\xi+\xi^2)=1\cdot(1,1,0,0)+(\xi+\xi^2)\cdot(0,0,1,1),$$
so every $A\in F$ intersects the rational subspace $B$ spanned by $(1,1,0,0)$ and $(0,0,1,1)$ nontrivially.